# How to get label name onclick from a React google 3D pie chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-charts

I am trying to get clicked section label name of the 3D Pie Chart Google

```
  <Chart
  chartType="PieChart"
  data={this.state.agentsummary}
  options={options}
  width={"100%"}
  height={"600px"}
  chartEvents={chartEvents}
  />
```

// but I got null value from row selection

```
const chartEvents = [
      {
        eventName: "select",
        callback({ chartWrapper }) {
          console.log("Selected ", chartWrapper.getChart().getSelection()[0]);
        },
      },
    ];
```